# Would it be OK to keep boa imperator terrarium not too far from tv screen?

Tags: snakes, terrariums, sound

I have two places I can keep terrarium for my new girl:

1. In my bedroom - calm and quiet, but lower ambient temperature.
2. In my living room - higher ambient temperature and more fun for me to watch, but relatively close to TV.

Snakes do have inner ears and can hear, so I wonder how much would it bother it to be in my living room. It would be nice to be able to watch her go about her business during work from home hours, and I would be able to monitor her temperature all day long.

I don't throw wild parties or anything and my house is non-smoking one.

Comment: Is it possible to install some kind of "wall" (foil at tank, plant, ...) between tank and tv? And do you know, if reptiles are able to see "faster light" than humans, for example single pictures of tv instead of motion pictures? (I know for turtles surely, but not for snakes, it is important for choosing light bulbs)

Comment: Vivarium has a very deep, moist substrate that should muffle a lot of sound. But specifically a screen no, I doubt I can. For the light, snake wouldn't see the screen at all